# Getting App/Widget on Homescreen?

Tags: android, homescreen, android-appwidget

I was wondering if it's possible to get the icon (shortcut) of your app on the home screen during installation instead of inside the standard apps folder ?
And I did find out that Android has AppWidgets but I was wondering if it supports "standard" widgets as well (javascript/html/css) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854197/how-can-i-place-app-icon-on-launcher-home-screen

It is possible now.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it doesn't support "standard" widgets (javascript/html/css), but you should take a look at the [Titanium Project](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/)

And there is no way to automatically put a shortcut on the homescreen when the application is installed. Not sure if most users would like that either.