# How can I place app icon on launcher home screen?

Tags: android

As you know, when app is nomally installed, icon is created at launcher menu screen.
What I want to do is create icon at user home screen during installation.
(without pressing icon for 5 seconds.)

I heard this from another source to just add

```
<category android:value="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml file, but it didn't work.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Do you not think this might be bad practice? If the user wants the icon on their screen, they can do it themselves very easily.

Comment: This is akin to those rage-inducing Windows applications that insist on adding themselves to the desktop on every install/upgrade/startup.  Even if you find a way, *please don't do it*.

Comment: @Jems, ZoogieZork you're both correct, but some situations will require this functionality, for example, a enterprise app store which is only available to employees on company owned devices.  A lot of these users will not have the knowledge to put applications on the home screen, but will have a much better user experience if we do it for them.

Comment: Also, some devices that are used for enterprises that develop multiple applications and need them all loaded onto the phone may need to do lots of testing. Before the testing they would need to load the apps onto the device and put the app on the homescreen, to make this easier, it would be nice to add the app to the homescreen automatically. Saving lots of time.

Comment: I disagree that this is bad practice. Many users I talk to expect the icon to appear and then decide for themselves what to do with it: move it, or trash it, or leave it....

Many users are miffed when they install an app, and can't find its icon on their home screen afterwards. Finding it in their apps menu is counter-intuitive to say the least....

Since the home screen is small and valuable real estate, users will not hesitate to rearrange or dump icons to suit their needs (much more intuitive). This is different from Windows desktop.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName("packageName", "className");
//shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "shortcut_name");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.icon));
//intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

You have to use following permission in your AndroidManaifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

You can use the commented code according to your requirements.

Note that, perhaps, above API is not documented. But it works.

Comment: For uninstalling the shortcut, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480287/trying-to-uninstall-shortcut-but-shortcut-wont-go-away/

Comment: Actually, as a newbie to Java, I could only make sense of this code from Kaillash's uninstall example. That example shows you can put it inside the main activity.
It seems though, that putting this code in the onCreate() event handler causes the shortcut to be created/recreated every time the app is launched. Any fix for that?

Comment: It works. But I think the option: intent.putExtra("duplicate", false); should be turned on by default to avoid duplication icon on homescreen

Comment: should shortcut icon be same as launcher icon? if yes, my launcher icon is placed in mimp folder instead of drawable folder, should i get shortcut icon resource from mimp folder?

Comment: It didn't work on my Samsung S7 edge, nor on my Nokia 8. I added this code in onCreate in MainActivity (which extends AppCompatActivity), I replaced context with getApplicationContext(), I replaced the package name by the corresponding, and the class name by "MainActivity". Any help.

Answer (score 9):

This is now solved by the Google Play services. You don't have to add any codes to do it anymore. Now when you install an app from the Google Play Store it automatically creates the logo in the main screen. It can be handled in the Google Play store settings.
Exception : If you are using any custom roms or launchers, it does not work with some.

Comment: Actually, this has been basic functionality since the beginning on Android - it has nothing to do with the play store or its services.

Comment: What if you don't want it? I have an app which only should be launched from an Intent of another app. But I have a launcher activity for settings. I don't want that the settings icon will be added to the homescreen by default.

Answer (score 7):

I use these methods to properly add or remove shortcuts. These methods are working pretty well and are the **same as the Android System when the user manually add/remove a shortcut**.

```
public static void addShortcut(Context context)
{
    Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();

    // Shortcut name
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appInfo.name);
    shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false); // Just create once

    // Setup activity shoud be shortcut object 
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(appInfo.packageName, appInfo.className);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(component));

    // Set shortcut icon
    ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, appInfo.icon);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);

    context.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}

public static void deleteShortcut(Context context)
{
    Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();

    // Shortcut name
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appInfo.name);

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(appInfo.packageName, appInfo.className);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));

    context.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}
```

Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: Is the broadcast receiver necessary ? Maybe addShortcut and deleteShortcut send a broadcast to com.android.launcher.action... package so why do we need a broadcast receiver ? And do we need to implement this new broadcast receiver in a class (which extends BroadcastReceiver) named "PackageReplacedReceiver" ? Please explain.

Comment: The broadcast receiver is optional of course, depending on if you want to do something when your package is replaced. Sorry, it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with the above answers and that's because API 22 and maybe other APIs returns on getApplicationInfo().className in debug/emulation mode:
"com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"

Most important thing is that I needed to set the entire path to the class for the class name. (see the changes)

For example, I had the following:
packageName=com.example.user.myapp
className=MainActivity
In [Kailash answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461755/5251010) I needed to change this line:

```
shortcutIntent.setClassName("packageName", "className");
```

to

```
shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.example.user.myapp", "com.example.user.myapp.MainActivity");
```

In [ChristopheCVBs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599712/5251010) I needed to change this line:

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(appInfo.packageName, appInfo.className);
```

to

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(appInfo.packageName, appInfo.packageName+".MainActivity");
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Robust Solution for all devices (Both `<26` or `>26`).

```
createShortcutOnHome(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToOpen.class, "app name", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

This method can be placed in your Util.

```
 public static void createShortcutOnHome(@NonNull Activity activity, Class activityToOpen, String title, @DrawableRes int icon) {
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(activity, activityToOpen);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // code for adding shortcut on pre oreo device 
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, title);
            intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            Parcelable parcelable = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(activity, icon);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, parcelable);
            activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
            System.out.println("added_to_homescreen");
        } else { 
            ShortcutManager shortcutManager = activity.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
            assert shortcutManager != null;
            if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
                ShortcutInfo pinShortcutInfo =
                        new ShortcutInfo.Builder(activity, "browser-shortcut-")
                                .setIntent(shortcutIntent)
                                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(activity, icon))
                                .setShortLabel(title)
                                .build();

                shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, null);
                System.out.println("added_to_homescreen");
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed_to_add");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ```shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a `setup` function that the user can use to do all potential actions. For example, make any necessary user-accessible folders(if they don't exist already), adding the shortcut to the home screen, and/or loading in initial data.

This is a function I'm actually writing now, so hopefully it turns out well. But yeah the point is to keep it out of the `onCreate()` so it doesn't get called every single time!

Comment: @Wytze: This is an answer-response to your last comment on Kailash's answer.