# IBM Worklight - Adding icon to android launcher during installation

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, launcher

Our customer asked us to let our Worklight 6.1-based application automatically install an icon on the launcher of the Android OS.

I found this Stack Overflow solution:
[How can I place app icon on launcher home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854197/how-can-i-place-app-icon-on-launcher-home-screen)

But, Worklight manages the changes to the AndroidManifest.xml file itself, and therefore I prefer not to mess around with this file myself if not needed. And if I have to modify this file, how would I register the java code included in the solution to be executed during or after installation of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think Worklight manages anything in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

It is the opposite - Worklight only generates this file for the application (inside the android\native folder) when you add the Android environment to your application via Worklight Studio, but this file is considered a "user file". You have the control over it and you can and **should** edit it to add this functionality.

Just like you would add to this file an `activity` when using the `WL.NativePage` API Worklight provides, then similarly if in Android the way to add an icon to the Android launcher is via a setting in `AndroidManifest.xml`, then do so.